# Approval bit not set for user x@y.z, yet messages from x@y.z require approval. Why?

Tags: mailman

See enclosed image

I have a list of users on a mailing list. Their approval bit is off, yet mailman requires an approval anyway. I want people not on the list to not be able to send messages, and people who are on the list to send messages without approval.

Thanks!

[image: approval bit off, yet requesting approval, why?]

Answer (score 0):

I set the value on the following page to no and it seems to work... for now:

https://example.com/cgi-bin/mailman/admin/email-example.com/?VARHELP=privacy/sender/default_member_moderation

In the above URL, change example.com with your actual domain and email-example.com with the actual email of your mailman list. For example, a@b.com should be a-b.com